# Join Validation Report Contains Invalid Character " "

Tags: attribute-joins

Very new to ArcGIS.  I am attempting to do a table join.  It is joining a shapefile of the us states with a CSV of import data.  However when I try to validate the join i get an error saying the fields contains invalid characters and it just shows a blank between two quotations.  However I have no quotations within my attribute data in the csv.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the joint validation window, the exclamation mark is for the "Check for field name that contain invalid characters".

The join validation report window list the 4 field that contain one or more space.

You need to remove all space from the field name in the csv and redo the join.

Comment: oh, i didn't realize i could not have spaces in the field names.  I joined them anyways and it seemed to work as i was able to make my map and the import data was now assigned to the states geography.

Comment: Yes, when using excel table or csv field name rules are not strongly enforced, you can use table with "wrong" field name but if you try to export or to join you usually run into problem...